# Best Practice for handling & naming intermediate/temporal variables in C#

Tags: c#, validation, parsing, type-conversion, code-structure

In my C# (.Net 6) backend (but also in other languages) I often face the problem, that I get an object which I need to validate and convert before using it. Currently I handle this by creating two variables: `fooRaw` and `foo`. I store the response to `fooRaw`, then I validate it. After that I parse it and store the result into `foo`.

I am not really convinced this is the best way of doing this - maybe someone out there can enlighten me or at least inspire me how I could improve this.

Two Examples:
Example 1:

```cs
List<FooType> fooRaw = GetFoos(filter: "id = '123'");
// id should be unique therefor only one result is valid
if(fooRaw.Count != 1){
    throw //...
}

FooType foo = fooRaw.First();
```

Example 2:

```cs
string fooRaw = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// I have a http response that i want to parse -> only works if string is not empty
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fooRaw)){
    throw //...
}

FooType foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooType>(fooRaw);
```

Any Ideas how I could improve this process or at least improve variable naming and readability?

Comment: Do you mean "temporary"?

Comment: Is this more a question for Stack Code Review rather then overflow?  Here we tackle problems, where in review they can help you with something like this a little better without people getting a little (lot) narky

Comment: `if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fooRaw)){` - so you throw an exception **IF fooRaw IS NOT Null or WhiteSpace** i.e. _has_ content?

Comment: @SimonPrice This question would be closed on Code Review as being too hypothetical. It is not real code from a real working project based on the type names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your solution is fine**, and the `Raw` suffix nicely indicates that this a raw, un-validated value. I would probably use `rawFoo` instead of `fooRaw`, since it sounds more "natural" (and Visual Studio won't suggest to auto-complete `fooRaw` if you start typing `foo`), but that might be a matter of taste.

If you want to avoid having the raw variable in scope after validation (lest someone might accidentally use it instead of the validated value) *and* your validation logic just throws exceptions, you can extract your validation logic into a separate method and avoid the intermediate variable:

```
var foo = ValidateFoo(GetRawFoo(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I need to name quick variables, then I do make them at least relatable to what they're supposed to retrieve, but I make it a shorter word, or a word without capitals, to indicate its short use.

like `var doc = document` or `var collect = Collection.FirstOrDefault()`

Still, I'd prefer not shortening them at all, and prioritise readability for it, as you need to understand it when someone else, or you a few months later, looks back at the code.